# How to troubleshoot missing OSM tiles in leaflet html widget?

Tags: html, leaflet, rstudio, openstreetmap, r-markdown

I need to create a web page that includes an interactive map where users can see popup information about data collected at many locations. Using Rstudio and leaflet on Windows, wanting to use OSM base map tiles.

My leaflet map works fine in Rstudio viewer. However, when the 'knitted' page is viewed in Firefox, no OSM map tiles appear although other components of the map are okay. Similarly OSM tiles missing in saved html widget.

I made a simple example to demonstrate.

````
```{r}
library(leaflet)
library(htmlwidgets)
rand_lng = function(n = 10) rnorm(n, 145.7, .01)
rand_lat = function(n = 10) rnorm(n, -17, .01)    
m = leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles(group = "OSM (default)") %>%
  addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery") %>%
  addCircleMarkers(rand_lng(5), rand_lat(5), group = "Points")%>% 
  addLayersControl(
    baseGroups = c("OSM (default)","Esri.WorldImagery"),
    overlayGroups = c("Points"),
    options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)) %>% 
  setView(lng = 145.7, lat = -17, zoom = 12)
m
saveWidget(m, "leaflet_OSMplusEsri.html")
```
````

[This is the output I get in Rstudio viewer, with OSM tiles selected and displayed correctly. When selected, Esri tiles are correct also.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOpXP.jpg)

[This is the html file shown in Firefox, where OSM tiles do not display despite being selected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vF59z.jpg)

I've been searching all day without discovering how to troubleshoot this. As a newbie perhaps I'm missing something obvious?

I will be very grateful for advice: how to troubleshoot this problem in simple steps?

Answer (score 3):

Took a long time, but I eventually resolved this. In case it helps anyone else, here is the revised version that works properly.

````
```{r}
library(leaflet)
library(htmlwidgets)
rand_lng = function(n = 10) rnorm(n, 145.7, .01)
rand_lat = function(n = 10) rnorm(n, -17, .01)
m = leaflet() %>% 
  addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap, group = "OSM") %>% 
  addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldImagery, group =  "Esri") %>%
  addCircleMarkers(rand_lng(5), rand_lat(5), group = "Points")%>% 
  addMiniMap() %>% 
  addLayersControl(
    baseGroups = c("OSM","Stamen", "Esri"),
    overlayGroups = c("Points"),
    options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)) %>% 
  setView(lng = 145.7, lat = -17, zoom = 12)
m
saveWidget(m, "leaflet_OSMplusEsri.html")
```
````

Cause of the problem was addTiles() with default values. I'm not sure why this did not work, hoping someone might be able to explain.